# c++ blank app connection with SQL server

Tags: c++, sql-server, connection-string

I want to connect c++ app with SQL server to retrieve information from there such as usernames and passwords but I don't know how to do it could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect with SQL server using user name and password. There is no way to retrieve user name / password without login to sql server.

Comment: yes and I want to know how to connect to SQL server and retrieve or add info in database